# How to choose num_workers for jetson-inference train.py on Jetson AGX Orin?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, nvidia-jetson

I recently started working with the **Jetson AGX Orin 64GB**. Im currently working through the Hello AI World and the **Transfer Learning Sections** of dusty's jetson-inference github [dusty's jetson-inference github](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/blob/master/docs/pytorch-cat-dog.md) and need help understanding/setting the --workers=N flag.

For the Transfer Learning with the ResNet-18 model with the cat_dog dataset, I was wondering which **number of workers** I should use. Im also new to Pytorch, so this is a first for me getting in contact with this. Online I found guidelines like num_workers = batch-size or num_workers = GPU Cores, but the training already fails at workers = 4, giving me the error "It is possible that dataloader's workers are out of shared memory", while the Jetson has 2048 GPU cores and 64GB of LPDDR5 RAM.

Im pretty sure I followed the tutorial correctly and Im running the training in the docker container, what am I doing wrong? Also, I expect the time needed per epoch to be faster with more workers, is that correct?